# How to get UIView given a CGPoint?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, touch, hittest

I am trying to find a way to get a particular `UIView` given a `CGPoint`. Briefly, I want to do a hit test.

For example, I have a `UIView` which has many subviews whose sizes are smaller than the parent `UIView`. What I want to do is, when a `touchMoved` event happens, to check the other subviews around the touched subview.
For that purpose, it would be nice to be able to convert a `CGPoint` to a subview `UIView`.

I'm new to Objective-C. Is there good way to do it?  Any suggestion would be really helpful. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a [hitTest:withEvent:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest:withEvent:) selector on UIView. This returns the deepest subview in the view hierarchy that contains that point. Try calling this on your topmost view.