# Detect selected view in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView which is horizontale scrollable. Inside this view I have added some views as subviews. How can I detect which view is in the middle of the screen and is selected by the user?

I thought of something like `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` just for a scroll view.

Thanks

Comment: No there isn't. But there is a delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll`, and different `contentOffset` & `contentSize` property, you can know what is showed.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand. Could you show me how to detect which view is selected?

Answer (score 0):

you can check `contentOffSet` property of `UIScrollView`  and then check for the view at that `CGPoint` in `scrollView`. you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033220/how-to-get-uiview-given-a-cgpoint) which shows how to get UIView from `CGPoint`.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch touches like this (from your `UIScrollView` subclass):

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint locationInScroll = [touch locationInView:scrollView];
        for (UIView *view in scrollView.subviews) {
            if (CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, locationInScroll)) {
                // that's it
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can try to use `UITapGestureRecognizer` in a similar way.

Comment: Is there a way do to this within the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:scrollView:`method?

Comment: You can get `scrollView.contentOffset` to get coordinates of top-left visible point and `scrollView.contentSize` to get visible size. But how do you expect user to "select" a view without tapping?

Answer (score 0):

In the touchesEnded or gesture recognizer function, get the exact point within the scroll view where the click is made.

```
CGPoint touchPoint=[gesture locationInView:scrollView];
```

Then divide the y value of the touchPoint with the height of each view to get the exact UIView within the scrollView

```
int point = (touchPoint.y) / heightOfSingleView;
```

Then get this particular view within the scrollview as follows:

```
UIView* view=[[locationInView:scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:point];
```

Exact code would look like this:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 CGPoint touchPoint=[gesture locationInView:scrollView];
 int point = (touchPoint.y) / heightOfSingleView;
 UIView* view=[[locationInView:scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:point];
}
```